# If I prepare a state (density matrix) in Gibbs state, does it go to the lowest energy state at very low temperature?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

Gibbs state is
$$\rho_G=\frac{1}{Z} e^{-H/kT} = \sum_n \frac{1}{Z} e^{-E_n/kT}|E_n⟩⟨E_n| \, . $$
If $T$ goes to zero, does it mean the $\rho_G$ goes to the lowest energy state $|E_0⟩⟨E_0|$?

Comment: What do you mean by "goes to" $\left \lvert E_n \right \rangle \left \langle E_n \right \rvert$? What is the $n$ index?

Comment: Sorry I corrected it.

Comment: After some research I found the answer is yes.

Comment: Ok well I took the time to write an answer...

Comment: Is this for a degenerate or non-degenerate ground state? If there is degeneracy, the Gibbs state will reduce at $T\to 0$ to the maximally mixed state confined to the ground state manifold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the probability of state $n$ divided by the probability of state 0:

$$\frac{\text{prob of }\left \lvert E_n \right \rangle}{\text{prob of }\left \lvert E_0 \right \rangle} = \frac{\exp \left( -E_n / k T \right)}{\exp \left( - E_0 / k T \right)} = \exp \left( - (E_n - E_0) / kT \right) \, .$$

If $E_n > E_0$, then as $T \rightarrow 0$ the probability ratio goes to $\exp(-\infty) \rightarrow 0$.
So yes, as $T \rightarrow 0$ the probability of the system to be in any state other than $\left \lvert E_0 \right \rangle$ goes to zero.
Therefore, the system goes to $\left \lvert E_0 \right \rangle$.

Comment: (... for a non-degenerate ground state.)